# i want to make a bot like giveaway bot this is my code

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

**command is not working and when i start it ( when it was working) bot doesnt ask question like in which channel he should host giveaway , time and winner .
i am noob in coding and also giveaway dont end after time up , please check it i am new to python and also dumb somehow i wrote this code but its no use**

```
from http import client
from lib2to3.pytree import convert
from turtle import color, pos, title
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import datetime
import random

class Giveawayk(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self , bot):
        self.bot = bot


    

    def convert(time):
        time_dict = {"s" : 1 , "m" : 60, "h" : 3600, "d" :3600*24}

        unit = time[-1]

        if unit not in pos:
            return -1 
        try:
            val = int(time[:-1])
        except:
            return -2
        
        return val * time_dict[unit]
  
        


        

    @commands.command
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
    async def giveaway(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("let's start with this giveaway! . Plz answer all question under 15 minutes ")

        questions = ["In which channel you want me to start a giveaway . Anser dont be shy",
                    "what should be the duration of giveaway? (s|m|h|d",
                    "what is the prize of giveaway dont tell me you want to do a giveaway without price"]

        anwers = []

        def check(m):
            return m.author ** ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

        for i in questions:
            await ctx.send(i)

            
                

# idk what to call this
       
            c_id = int(anwers[0][2:-1])
            channel = client.get_channel(c_id)

        time = convert(anwers[1])
        if time == -1:
            await ctx.send("Bruh tell me time i cant host a giveaway without it btw i want to become next iron man")
            return
        elif time== -2:
            await ctx.send('time must be an integer  - Smart bot')

        prize = anwers[2]


        await ctx.send(f"Ok i do for you in {channel.mention}")

        embed = discord.Embed(title = "Giveaway" , description = f"{prize}", color = ctx.guild.me.top_role.color,)
        embed.add_field(name="Hosted by" , value = ctx.author.mention)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"ends {anwers[1]} From now")

        my_msg = await channel.send(embed = embed)

        await my_msg.add_reaction("")

        await asyncio.sleep(time)

        users = await users.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(client.user))

        King = random.choice(users)

        await channel.send(f"congratulations {King.mention} you won i never won a giveaway but you won wait does this mean you are better then me ?")
              

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
    async def reroll(self, ctx , channel : discord.TextChannel, id_ : int):
        try:
            new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(id_)
        except:
            await ctx.send('ID was entered incorrectly hmmm , wait Batman ?')
            return
        users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(client.user))

        winner = random.choice(users)

        await channel.send(f"Congratulations the new winner is {winner.mention} Rip old winner")

          

#end
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Giveawayk(bot))
```

**Try to help plz**

Answer (score 0):

So your file makeup is quite odd in my eyes. Here's how I usually like to set up bots.

```
import discord
import asyncio
import random

from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

#### Might be helpful in your case, just remember to include the intent in the discord developer portal
#### Remove these lines if you don't want the hassle
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
####


# client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".") if you removed the intents
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents = intents)

#if you want to make a custom help command
client.remove_command('help')

#obligatory on_ready
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

@client.command(aliases=["p"])
@commands.has_role(<role ID>)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong")

client.run("token_here")
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The poster wants to fix their giveaway command.